# OpenThread Border Router not sending back child ID response

Tags: openthread

I setup a OpenThread Border Router on a Raspberry PI With EFR32MG12 as an RCP, But Whenever I tries to connect a child Node to my Border Router it Shows **Detached** State. When I looked In to the Network Analyzer Border Router is not sending back the Child ID Response for the Child ID Request. But When I Tried WithOut a Border Router Iam Getting Proper Responses and state as Child. Just started working on thread my knowledge is very little here.Any Help Please

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was recently reported and a fix submitted in https://github.com/openthread/ot-br-posix/pull/881. Try with the latest main branch to see if your issue has been resolved.